# How can i make a dll for my c# project from a linux/mac os supported 3rd party code?

Tags: c#, c++, linux, g++, cross-compiling

I have one 3rd party c++ project which doesn't support windows and now I am looking for a way to do cross-compile that code and make a dll out of that so I can use that in my c# code.
This is the 3rd party code(https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2) am looking to make dll file for my windows c# project.
Any suggestion or help ?

Comment: Use standard c-language libraries which will work on multiple operating systems.  Many people will write in c++ and then create a wrapper class so that the c++ code can be called from c#.  The wrapper will simply take a parameter list from c# and call a c++ method with same parameters.

Comment: Can anyone help me to generate dll from there

Comment: To really answer your question requires a full semester class.  The Computer Scientist at Bell Labs in the 1970's (K & R) tackled the problem and developed c language and Unix to answer the question.  Their dll were 84 macros that were written in assembly language and a compiler using the dll.  They were then able on a PDP 11 were able to compile code and create unix using the dll.  Later wrote the 84 macros on different manufacture computers and got unix running on any machine.Your dll is the 84 macros which are the same methods but written for different machines (wrappers).Then called by c#.

Comment: @KNP You can disregard the comment above. Unfortunately we do have some users on the site who are prone to such utterances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in an [issue](https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2/issues/47) on the official repository, the `iso_wg3` branch supports Windows builds and the [README.md](https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2/blob/iso_wg3/README.md) includes build instructions.

Comment: where is this branch

Comment: The readme link is already in that branch. https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2/tree/iso_wg3

Comment: found it, am looking through it now. sorry am new into this thats why struggling

Comment: thanks, am trying to look tutorial for building this now

Comment: sorry to ask more, can u help me in this to build and getting an out put dll?