# How to geenrate dll from github c++ project?

Tags: c++, macos, cross-compiling

Am trying to follow the steps mentioned to follow from mac machine to create a dll from this project (https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2/tree/iso_wg3) ..Can any one help me with proper steps how to get dll from above github?

Comment: Its not going to be easy to cross compile this. Which compiler do you want the `dll` to work with? I mean if you build this with `mingw` the `dll` created likely would not work with Visual Studio.

Comment: If the answer to [How can i make a dll for my c# project from a linux/mac os supported 3rd party code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58824320/205233) did not solve your problem why did you accept it? Basically you are re-posting the same problem but with less context.

Comment: that question is for Windows, this one is for Mac perhaps?

Comment: is there any way to get dlls?

Comment: Sadly, they've use an MSBuild solution for the windows port. Here is a madman's solution: https://github.com/paleozogt/MSVCDocker